# how to create a grid of images

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile

I want to create a landing/welcome page for a mobile application with a grid of images.
I am not sure how to do it.
I saw few resources where people are doing it purely with CSS3.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stucKrWheVM

http://alijafarian.com/responsive-image-grids-using-css/

Some are using two versions of images , one for thumbnail, one for larger image.
Others are using single version of image and it is automatically scaled to different sizes.

Could you please let me know what is the best way to do it ?

Do I have to use multiple versions(sizes) of each image for different devices with different screen sizes ?If yes how can I find all the sizes required ?
Do I have to do it purely with CSS , ignoring jQuery provided in my app.

I tried creating a grid using jquery mobile sample code and it was horrible :

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="grid1.html"><img src="images/icon.png"/></a><p>Text</p></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="grid1.html"><img src="images/paris.jpg"/></a></div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">Grid3</div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">Grid4</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">Grid5</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">Grid6</div>
            </div>
```

I need an advice on how to proceed

Comment: Any advice please ? I am trying to develop on Worklight 6.3

Comment: The Grid will work fine for mixed content. I see you're shooting for a 3 column grid?

Comment: If you need to create thumbnails, that is not something you can do easily. Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: have a look at this JQM responsive grid demo and check the css on how it works. with some modifications to the code you can have a nice scalabe grid system for any size screens --- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/listview-grid/listview-grid.html